# Double asterisks in "Pay it forward" section, "How to Answer"

Tags: bug, answers

Please see "Pay it forward" in ["How to Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Point of concern:

> Instead, **vote up** the answers

I noted that the double asterisks seem a bit out of place. Was this meant to be some sort of emphasis, in which case it should be either *italicized* or **bolded**?

Comment: Oh Markdown, sometimes we wonder about you... (`**text**` is meant to be emphasised as **bold text**.)

Comment: Well, it **used** to support markdown: http://web.archive.org/web/20120122184111/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer so at some point a code change ripped markdown support in help center and left the text naked.

Comment: @michaelb958 That's that I thought too... but I wasn't sure if it was intentional.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The other example of "**vote up**" is fine, and so's the "set a bounty" link; can't be total Markdown failure.

Comment: @michaelb958 Maybe there was some migration from markdown to HTML, and it ended up being escaped?

Comment: @michael right... let the devs solve the mystery then! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not from StackOverflow's team (*Obviously!*).

But I put forward my views.

Any text wrapped inside double asterisks (**) but outside of markdown context is meant to be emphasized.

And I believe the page is out of mark down context.

I think the page is just html, otherwise ** should have been rendered as well.

So here double asterisks mean emphasization of the word. If they wanted to make it bold, they could have done it easily. It was not meant to be either italicized or bolded. I think, they wanted it to stand out from the rest.

Comment: Good point. But in that case, why not make it bold or italicized? Those are better ways to express emphasis than adding double asterisks.